# ps command: Practical difference between the -p and -q options

Tags: ps, options

According with `man ps` exists:

```
 -p pidlist
    Select by PID.  
    This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist.  
    Identical to p and --pid.

 -q pidlist
    Select by PID (quick mode).  
    This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist.  
    With this option ps reads the necessary info only for the pids listed in the
    pidlist and doesn't apply additional filtering rules. 
    The order of pids is unsorted and preserved. 
    No additional selection options, sorting and forest type listings are allowed in this mode.  
    Identical to q and --quick-pid.
```

So far: `ps -p 100 101 102` returns:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  100 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
  101 ?        I<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
  102 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
```

`ps -q 100 101 102` returns

```
q/-q/--quick-pid cannot be combined with other selection options.
```

and `ps -q 100,101,102` returns

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  100 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
  101 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_0
  102 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
```

Until there are two differences:

- Syntax is similar (space vs commas) to list the pids
- If the header `STAT` is included or not in the output

**Question:**

- What are the other scenarios mentioned in `-q` where it is mandatory over `-p`?

**Extra Question:**

- What does *Select by PID (quick mode)* mean?

Some examples are appreciated for a complete understanding

Comment: Also compare `ps 102 101 100` and `ps -p 102,101,100` and `ps -q 102,101,100`. `ps -p 100 101 102` is really `ps 101 102` with `-p 100`; it’s not using “100 101 102” as arguments to `-p` itself directly.

Comment: @StephenKitt about _"ps -p 100 101 102 is really ps 101 102 with -p 100"_ can you pls expand/clarify that part? Thank You.