# ps command: how does the '-q' option work?

Tags: ps, man, options

According with the `ps` command, for the `-q` option

Through the `man` is indicated:

```
 -q pidlist
        Select by PID (quick mode). This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear 
        in pidlist. With this option ps reads the necessary info only for the pids listed in 
        the pidlist and doesn't apply additional filtering rules. The order of pids is 
        unsorted and preserved. No additional selection options, sorting and forest type 
        listings are allowed in this mode. Identical to q and --quick-pid.
```

And through `ps --help a`

```
 -q, q, --quick-pid <PID>
                      process id (quick mode)
```

But is not clear for me about the following parts:

**Questions**

1. What does *(quick mode)* mean? - *quick* about what?
2. What does *With this option ps reads the necessary info only for the pids listed in the pidlist and doesn't apply additional filtering rules* mean?
3. What does *The order of pids is unsorted and preserved* mean? - why is *unsorted* if theoretically we are defining the explicit set of pids? I mean `ps -q <pid1>,<pid2>,...,<pidN>`
4. Therefore with these three first questions: When is mandatory use this `-q` option?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701875/ps-command-practical-difference-between-the-p-and-q-options and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486029/what-exactly-does-ps-p-pid-do-that-ps-q-pid-does-not

Comment: @Manuel in future, when you ask a question which is highly related to other questions on the site that you know about, please refer to them in your new question and explain what you think is missing in the existing answers.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, they are related, but my intention was avoid do verbose referring to other question/solution for each point and therefore do a spaghetti among them. Furthermore in this question, are more specific questions by content

Comment: @Manuel by not referring to them, you risk people suggesting that this question is a duplicate of, for example, [What exactly does `ps -p PID` do that `ps -q PID` does not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486029/86440) If you want to avoid that, you need to explain that you’re aware of that question, and explain why your question is different. It doesn’t have to be long, just a quick mention at the start of your question.

Comment: Agree, but I didn't want do an offense the other answers - it to avoid a wrong interpretation of the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually, `ps` retrieves information about *all* the processes in the system, before applying any filters. `-q` is quick because it disables this behaviour: with `-q`, `ps` only retrieves information for the listed pids.
2. See above.
3. Without `-q`, `ps` sorts its output according to its sort parameters. By default, it sorts by pid, so `ps 102 101 100` will show pids 100, 101, and 102 (if they exist) in that order. `-q` doesn’t sort, so `ps -q 102,101,100` will show pids 102, 101, and 100 in that order.
4. It’s an option, it’s never mandatory. It’s useful if you want information on specific pids and nothing else; in such cases it can save a significant amount of time.